# Hide/show div on mouseover/mouseout

Tags: javascript, html

First to say I am not Javascript developer at all, but I need small help of Javascript.
I have a.php file, it contains div, and I am going to include another file into it.

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="unityObject">div content</div>

<?php include_once('includes/b.php') ?>

</body>
</html>
```

b.php looks like this:

```
<nav id="myNavigation">
"content"
</nav>
```

Now what I need is this: when mouse is over "myNaviagtion", hide "unityObject", if mouse is out, then show "unityObject" again.

I can use this simple code to hide "unityObject":

```
<nav id="myNavigation"
onmouseover="document.getElementById ('unityObject').style.visibility = 'hidden';">
```

Now if I want to show "unityObject" again, I need to check if someVar is true. For example:

```
if (someVar)
{
 "unityObject".style.visibility = "visible";
}
else
{
 "unityObject".style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

But I do know know how to put all this code together, and I cannot use simple code as

```
"onmouseout="document.getElementById ('unityObject').style.visibility = `'visible';"
```

cause it deos not check for someVar.

Comment: `onmouseout="document.getElementById('unityObject').style.visibility = someVar ? 'visible' : 'hidden';"`

Comment: Just a note: When `someVar` becomes true, you would have to mouseover and mouseout again to make it visible!?!?!

Comment: If you are open to using JQuery you could check out: [jQuery:Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 0):

First, i suggest you add a CSS class to your elements with javascript instead of manipulating inline styles, it's suggested to do so to clearly separate structure/content (HTML), style (CSS) and behavior (Javascript). In the same line of thought, I'm proposing a solution which does not use inline event handlers, and instead uses the addEventListener method on your elements, [as is suggested on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event)

the following, while far from being optimal, is the code you basicaly need. Insert this code in a `<script>` tag before the closing `</body>` tag of your HTML template.

```
var d = document.getElementById('unityObject'),
    n = document.getElementById('myNavigation');

n.addEventListener('mouseover', hideDiv, true);
n.addEventListener('mouseout', showDiv, true);

function hideDiv(e) {
  d.className = 'hide';
}

function showDiv(e) {
 d.className = 'show';
}
```

then you add CSS for styling the `show` and `hide` classes:

```
.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: While using `.className` works, it should be noted that it prevents the OP from attaching any other custom CSS classes to `unityObject` as those will be wiped out when you assign the `hide` & `show` classes in your javascript.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. As mentionned my solution is a quick one. You could create a custom function to apppend/remove class names if you need to support multiple class names, or use classList.

Answer (score 0):

you can use function for onmouseover. like

```
    <nav id="myNavigation"
onmouseover="hideUnityObject()">
```

and after that in somewhere in your html code you can use something like this.

```
<script>
    function hideUnityObject(){

         if (someVar){
         "unityObject".style.visibility = "visible";
        }else{
         "unityObject".style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }            
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried this before posting a question here, I find that code on google, but it does not call a function hideUnityObject. I do not really understand.